# Can't select View Content dropdown when adding view in MVC using Interfaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, scaffolding, strongly-typed-view

I have my **Model** defined externally in two projects - a **Core** project and an **Interface** project.

I am opening the **Add View** dialogue from my controller, and selecting **Create a strongly typed view**.

In the drop down list, I can select the concrete types like **MyProject.Model.Core.OrderDetails**, but the interface types like **MyProject.Model.Interface.IOrderDetails** aren't there.

I can type the interface class in manually and everything works, but then the **View content** menu that lets you select the Create, Delete, List, etc scaffolding is disabled.

Is there some problem with using interfaces in MVC? Or is it something else I'm missing?

**Edit:** Just to clarify, if I select the concrete object and the whatever scaffolding I want, I can then edit the `Inherits` tag in the view Page directive and everything works fine, so there's no missing references or anything. It's just the wizard doesn't seem to want to work with the interface.

Comment: +1 for your username. 401 is a joke.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could always select the concrete class implementing the interface, generate the partial view, and manually remove all the stuff that's not needed.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment. It's not really a problem, more something I found curious as if this is a known issue with MVC it's pretty lame. Isn't one of the main goals of MVC to promote loose coupling?